# Payday 2 on Linux: locked at 60fps with NVIDIA's Kernel Mode Setting

Tags: technical-issues, payday-2, linux

I use Nvidia's DRM (Direct Rendering Manager) Kernel Mode Setting (see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#DRM_kernel_mode_setting)) to get rid of screen tearing on my desktop. I've also tried to use compton to get rid of screen tearing but their solution doesn't seem to do anything.

Sadly this also locks my fps to 60 in Payday 2 and it causes tons of mouse input lag, making aiming very difficult. The vsync or max fps settings don't do anything.

I don't have this problem with any other game.

These are my laptop specs:

- i7 7700HQ with Intel HD Graphics 630 (but using dedicated GPU of course. Both are enabled in BIOS settings)
- GTX 1050 2GB VRAM (with latest proprietary drivers)
- 8GB RAM

Disabling DRM KMS fixes the issue, but I want to keep it enabled to fix screen tearing on my desktop.

---

Things I've tried so far:

- Adding `vblank_mode=0 %command%` to launch options
- Turning vsync on and off again
- Setting an fps limit in-game
- https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Payday_2#60.2B_FPS_not_applying_in_settings
- https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Payday_2#Mouse_input_delay

None of these work for me.

---

Can anyone, who also has Payday 2 and an NVIDIA GPU, enable DRM KMS and see what happens?

Comment: I initially thought this was referring to a different kind of DRM you often encounter with games.

Comment: I edited the post and title :)